# Is it possible to embed a pdf reader in QupZilla browser?

Tags: 14.04, pdf, browser, evince, qupzilla

I have recently started using [QupZilla browser](http://www.qupzilla.com) with Ubuntu 14.04 and while I like its slimmed down browsing experience one thing that bugs me is that when I wish to view a pdf I only have the option to open externally or save.

I would like a way to view a pdf within the browser if this is possible. While I use Evince I am open to another package as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Install the Kparts Plugins

As per this [german wiki page](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/QupZilla#KParts-Plugin) the kparts-plugins can be used.

You need have the [universe repository activated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Then issue the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install kpartsplugin
```

Beware that if you don't have the KDE-Desktop installed already, on a Ubuntu 14.04 those packages will be installed with the kpartsplugin package:

> kdelibs5-data libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libkdecore5 libkdeui5 libkio5 libkparts4 libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 soprano-daemon

#### Update

On my Ubuntu 14.04 running Unity clicking a link won't open it in the browser, but will give me the choice to either save it or open it in a external application. I don't know why this doesn't work (ie. it doesn't work!). Since the kparts plugin is loaded I suspect it must be a error in the kparts plugin configuration.

Until now I've just translated and copied the relevant stuff from what others said. Since the OP said he couldn't make it work (see comments) I've tested myself and lo-and-behold I can't make it work either.

Comment: @DKBose I didn't translate it right. Corrected and added what will be installed starting from a 14.04 live-USB stick.

Comment: @MadMike Have you tested this with qupzilla? I have downloaded the package but I still can't get the pdfs to open within the browser. Is there other settings I need to change?

Comment: @DKBose Can't make it work either. Updated my answer accordingly. Are you running Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity (I don't know if that matters, but well.. )

Comment: @MadMike I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. One strange thing I noted was when I run Qupzilla as Sudo(just did this once to see if it had any effect) it will open pdfs with Okular externally but not embedded. When I run Qupzilla as a regular user it opens pdfs externally with evince.